# debconf is broken, can't install anything anymore

Tags: apt, raspberry-pi, raspbian, dpkg, debconf

I tried to install docker on my raspbian install and accidentally broke `apt-get`

If I run `apt-get install` or `upgrade`, I get the following error:

```
E: The package debconf needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

I've tried all the suggested solutions I could find online, some examples:

Command:

```
apt-get -f install debconf
```

Result:

```
root@raspberrypi:~# apt-get -f install debconf
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: The package debconf needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

Command:

```
dpkg-reconfigure debconf
```

Result:

```
root@raspberrypi:~# dpkg-reconfigure debconf
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: debconf is broken or not fully installed
```

Command:

```
apt-get install --reinstall debconf
```

Result:

```
root@raspberrypi:~# apt-get install --reinstall debconf
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: The package debconf needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

Command:

```
dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq debconf
```

Result:

```
root@raspberrypi:/var/cache/apt/archives# dpkg-reconfigure debconf
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: debconf is broken or not fully installed
root@raspberrypi:/var/cache/apt/archives# sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up libc6-dbg:armhf (2.19-18+deb8u10) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of debconf-i18n:
debconf-i18n depends on debconf (= 1.5.56+deb8u1); however:
Version of debconf on system is 1.5.56.

dpkg: error processing package debconf-i18n (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of debconf-utils:
debconf-utils depends on debconf (= 1.5.56+deb8u1); however:
Version of debconf on system is 1.5.56.

dpkg: error processing package debconf-utils (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up python-software-properties (0.92.25debian1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-software-properties (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up perl-modules (5.20.2-3+deb8u8) ...
Setting up perl (5.20.2-3+deb8u8) ...
Setting up libtirpc1:armhf (0.2.5-1+deb8u1) ...
Setting up libc-dev-bin (2.19-18+deb8u10) ...
Setting up libperl5.20 (5.20.2-3+deb8u8) ...
Setting up libc6-dev:armhf (2.19-18+deb8u10) ...
Setting up rpcbind (0.2.1-6+deb8u2) ...
insserv: warning: current start runlevel(s) (empty) of script `rpcbind' overrides LSB defaults (S).
insserv: warning: current stop runlevel(s) (0 1 6 S) of script `rpcbind' overrides LSB defaults (0 1 6).
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-18+deb8u10) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
debconf-i18n
debconf-utils
python-software-properties
root@raspberrypi:/var/cache/apt/archives# sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: The package debconf needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
root@raspberrypi:/var/cache/apt/archives# sudo dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of debconf-i18n:
debconf-i18n depends on debconf (= 1.5.56+deb8u1); however:
Version of debconf on system is 1.5.56.

dpkg: error processing package debconf-i18n (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of debconf-utils:
debconf-utils depends on debconf (= 1.5.56+deb8u1); however:
Version of debconf on system is 1.5.56.

dpkg: error processing package debconf-utils (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up python-software-properties (0.92.25debian1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-software-properties (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
debconf-i18n
debconf-utils
python-software-properties
root@raspberrypi:/var/cache/apt/archives# apt-get -f install debconf
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: The package debconf needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
root@raspberrypi:/var/cache/apt/archives# cd
root@raspberrypi:~# apt-get -f install debconf
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: The package debconf needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
root@raspberrypi:~# dpkg-reconfigure debconf
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: debconf is broken or not fully installed
root@raspberrypi:~# apt-get install --reinstall debconf
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: The package debconf needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
root@raspberrypi:~# dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq debconf
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of debconf:
tasksel depends on debconf (>= 0.5) | debconf-2.0; however:
Package debconf is to be removed.
Package debconf-2.0 is not installed.
Package debconf which provides debconf-2.0 is to be removed.
tasksel depends on debconf (>= 1.5.34) | cdebconf (>= 0.106); however:
Package debconf is to be removed.
Package cdebconf is not installed.
tasksel depends on debconf (>= 0.5) | debconf-2.0; however:
Package debconf is to be removed.
Package debconf-2.0 is not installed.
Package debconf which provides debconf-2.0 is to be removed.
tasksel depends on debconf (>= 1.5.34) | cdebconf (>= 0.106); however:
Package debconf is to be removed.
Package cdebconf is not installed.
locales depends on debconf (>= 0.5) | debconf-2.0; however:
Package debconf is to be removed.
Package debconf-2.0 is not installed.
Package debconf which provides debconf-2.0 is to be removed.
ca-certificates depends on debconf (>= 0.5) | debconf-2.0; however:
Package debcon
dpkg: error processing package debconf (--remove):
dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
debconf
```

Command:

```
dpkg --configure -a
```

Result:

```
root@raspberrypi:~# dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of debconf-i18n:
debconf-i18n depends on debconf (= 1.5.56+deb8u1); however:
Version of debconf on system is 1.5.56.

dpkg: error processing package debconf-i18n (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of debconf-utils:
debconf-utils depends on debconf (= 1.5.56+deb8u1); however:
Version of debconf on system is 1.5.56.

dpkg: error processing package debconf-utils (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up python-software-properties (0.92.25debian1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-software-properties (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
debconf-i18n
debconf-utils
python-software-properties
```

Command:

```
dpkg -C
```

Result:

```
The following packages are in a mess due to serious problems during
installation.  They must be reinstalled for them (and any packages
that depend on them) to function properly:
debconf              Debian configuration management system

The following packages have been unpacked but not yet configured.
They must be configured using dpkg --configure or the configure
menu option in dselect for them to work:
debconf-i18n         full internationalization support for debconf
debconf-utils        debconf utilities

The following packages are only half configured, probably due to problems
configuring them the first time.  The configuration should be retried using
dpkg --configure <package> or the configure menu option in dselect:
python-software-properties manage the repositories that you install software f
```

Command:

```
apt-cache policy
```

Result:

```
root@raspberrypi:~# apt-cache policy
Package files:
100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
    release a=now
500 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ jessie/ui armhf Packages
    release o=Raspberry Pi Foundation,a=stable,n=jessie,l=Raspberry Pi Foundation,c=ui
    origin archive.raspberrypi.org
500 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ jessie/main armhf Packages
    release o=Raspberry Pi Foundation,a=stable,n=jessie,l=Raspberry Pi Foundation,c=main
    origin archive.raspberrypi.org
Pinned packages:
```

Command:

```
apt-get -f install
```

Result:

```
root@raspberrypi:~# apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: The package debconf needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

Command:

```
cat /etc/*-release
```

Result:

```
root@raspberrypi:~# cat /etc/*-release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

Command:

```
apt-cache policy debconf debconf-i18n debconf-utils
```

Result:

```
root@raspberrypi:~# apt-cache policy debconf debconf-i18n debconf-utils
debconf:
Installed: 1.5.56
Candidate: 1.5.56
Version table:
*** 1.5.56 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
debconf-i18n:
Installed: 1.5.56+deb8u1
Candidate: 1.5.56+deb8u1
Version table:
*** 1.5.56+deb8u1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
debconf-utils:
Installed: 1.5.56+deb8u1
Candidate: 1.5.56+deb8u1
Version table:
*** 1.5.56+deb8u1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Command:

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Result:

```
root@raspberrypi:~# cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
```

Command:

```
ls -Al /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
```

Result:

```
root@raspberrypi:~# ls -Al /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 193 Apr 10 09:58 raspi.list
```

Command:

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list
```

Result:

```
root@raspberrypi:~# cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list
deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ jessie main ui
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ jessie main ui
```

Anyone have any clue what to try next?

Would love not to have to reinstall the OS.

Comment: Please paste the output for the commands you have listed above. Without that, we have no information about what is going on.

Comment: There, updated the post. Any suggestions?

Comment: Thank you, that's informative. Can you add the output of `dpkg -C`, please? And also paste the output of `apt-cache policy`. And what release of raspbian is this? "debconf-utils depends on debconf (= 1.5.56+deb8u1); however:
Version of debconf on system is 1.5.56." suggests you have a version mismatch. Also, `apt-get -f install debconf` is not correct syntax. It's just `apt-get -f install`. You might as well add the output for that too.

Comment: There we go, updated with the suggested commands and the output from cat /etc/*-release for os info. Need anything else?

Comment: No, just `apt-get -f install`. You did `apt-get -f install debconf` again. You now have that twice. And yes, let's have the output of `apt-cache policy debconf debconf-i18n debconf-utils`.

Comment: oh, mb fixed it now. same output though

Comment: Your debconf packages don't seem to have versions in the apt archives, which is strange. Can you paste `/etc/apt/sources.list`? And are those sources complete?

Comment: There, updated post with output from `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: This can't be right. You have only one line in your `/etc/apt/sources.list`, which is commented out! And is a `deb-src` line, what's more. Is that the entirety of what is in your `sources.list`? Please also check if there are any files in `/etc/apt/sources.d`, and if so, please paste the output of those files.

Comment: Yeah, that's all that's in sources.list. Added the list of files in sources.list.d and the content of that file. Thank you for taking time to help me with this.

Comment: Run `apt-get update`, and post your `apt-cache policy`.

Comment: Braiam ´apt-cache policy´ prints the same as already described in post both before and after ´apt-get update´

Comment: Note that in one place you have a url which is http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ and in another http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/. Figure out which one is correct. They probably both are not. There is actually a Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange you could ask at.

Comment: @FaheemMitha both of those should be there on Raspbian.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing your main Raspbian archive, which should be in your sources.list:

```
anthony@Kilby:~ $ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
```

Without that, there is nowhere to download debconf 1.5.56+deb8u1 from.

It's likely that adding the source back, then `apt-get update`, then `apt-get install -f` will be sufficient to fix it. If not, you'll need to manually download http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/d/debconf/debconf_1.5.56+deb8u1_all.deb and install it with `dpkg -i debconf_1.5.56+deb8u1_all.deb`. Ways of manually downloading that include wget/curl or `apt-get download debconf=1.5.56+deb8u1`. The latter is easiest if it works.

Comment: That seems to solve the problem partly, i no longer get ´E: The package debconf needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.´ instead i get this when trying to install things: https://gist.github.com/bobbzorzen/28bb22ecfdabbb76a118be81602b25c4
Is this an unrelated error? if so i'll accept your answer.

Comment: Seems like i had gotten python 3.4.x as my default version so that messed up with some python 2.7 install scripts. changed it back using `update-alternatives` and now it seems to work. Thanks everyone :)

Comment: You saved my life : Btw, the link to the package should be updated it is dead